# React Router v4 - Way to get collection of Routes that match a path?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am looking for a `children`-like mechanism for all Routes that match their `path` prop.

Initially I was thinking along the lines of just checking the `children` of a `SplitView`. Though I realize now that the `Routes` themselves will be the `children` and not the components they render.

Use Case:
 Our application will render content in one of two halves of the viewport.

- If there were no `children` in one `SplitView`, the other `SplitView` would expand to take up the full height of the viewport -- otherwise it's a 50/50 split.

  - The solution to this one may just be a flexbox one over a count on `children`...
- If `children.length` of the bottom `SplitView` were 0, than the `<Header />` would not get rendered.
- If either `SplitView`'s `children.length > 1`, than we would generate tabs for, or make "swipeable", the content of that split.

Though any matches of a `Route` will always be a sub-component of that `Route` and `children` of a `SplitView` will always be just the number of Routes pre-defined in a `SplitView`. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I don't doubt that there may be a better approach to achieve what I am aiming to do here and welcome alternatives in that regard as well.

Code Sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/x9mpl34jvw

```
  <SplitView>
    <Route path={["/foo", "/bar"]} component={ContainerA} />
    <Route path="/baz" component={ContainerB} />
    <Route path="/bob" component={ContainerG} />
  </SplitView>

  { onlyIfMatchesInBottomSplit && <Header /> }

  <SplitView>
    <Route path="/foo" component={ContainerC} />
    <Route path="/bar" component={ContainerD} />
    <Route path="/baz" component={ContainerE} />
    <Route path="/dob" component={ContainerF} />
  </SplitView>
```

/foo

```
+ - +
| A |
+ - +
| C |
+ - +
```

/bar

```
+ - +
| A |
+ - +
| D |
+ - +
```

/baz

```
+ - +
| B |
+ - +
| E |
+ - +
```

/dob

```
+ - +
|   |
+ F +
|   |
+ - +
```

To be clear, the issue is not in getting the components rendering in the right combinations, that part it working fine. It's being able to capture in an array the components that got rendered for each `SplitView` so they can be operated on in the same way as you would `children`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it inside the Route by using the render method and the props.match field.
Your route will need to become

```
<Route path="/baz" render={(props) => {
          console.log(props.match.url===props.match.path); //will return true when there is a match.
          return <ContainerB />;
        }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just use the render function to render each of the four routes like below, instead of splitting it up into seven (only making an example of the first one):

```
<Route path="/foo" render={(props) => 
       <div>
           <SplitView>
             <ContainerA {...props} />
           </SplitView>
           <Header />
           <SplitView>
             <ContainerC {...props} />
           </SplitView>
        </div>
    }}
/>
```

Comment:  Paul! The issue there appears that I would be generating a `Route` for every pairing of the splits which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Ah, yes. I see. I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way in documenation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/children-func

Just use children, it will return match === null if there is no match for this url:

```
<Route path={to} children={({ match }) => (
  <li className={match ? 'active' : ''}>
    <Link to={to} {...rest}/>
  </li>
)}/>
```